# How do I show the paths of a package in aptitude?

Tags: package-management, aptitude

I know how to show the paths where I installed a package with dpkg:

```
$ dpkg -L gnome
```

How can I do that with aptitude?

Comment: Why do you want to use `aptitude` when it's perfectly possible with `dpkg`? I din't even know it was possible. Thanks for that.

Comment: @RobinJ `dpkg -S` (what package does a file or directory belong to?) and `apt-file` (like `dpkg -S` and `dpkg -L`, but also for packages that are not installed) are other useful commands

Answer (score 2):

`dpkg` is a lower-level tool that needs to know where files are extracted and such, but `aptitude` and `apt` handle packages as a whole (using package names) and therefore don't provide a method for showing filenames.